# Unsigned double in C++?

Tags: c++, double, unsigned

Why doesn't C++ support unsigned double syntax?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Because typical floating point formats don't support unsigned numbers. See, for instance, [this list of IEEE 754 formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Formats).

Adding a numerical format that isn't supported by common hardware just makes life difficult for compiler writers, and is probably not considered worth the effort.

Comment: Also the *idea* is with floating point. That **Any** number should be representable, including the negative integers out to infinity. Unsigned numbers are counterproductive to this goal.

Comment: Erm, no, that's not the point. Or if it is the point, then all floating point types are doomed to failure. The set of numbers that can ever be represented in a meaningful way in a computer is countable...

Answer (score 20):

C++ doesn't support unsigned floating point types because most floating point hardware doesn't support unsigned floating point types. Some graphics cards do work with unsigned floating point, but it's generally internal, not really visible to a program or user.

Answer (score 7):

Unsigned integers gain an extra bit of precision and have slightly different bit-wise semantics to signed integers. Floats and doubles always reserve a bit for the sign (on most hardware) and have no bit-wise semantics, so there's no real benefit in having an unsigned real type.

Comment: You theoretically *could* use that bit for the mantissa or exponent, though, increasing either range or accuracy.

Comment: Well I wanted a unsigned double to control that it's always a positive number without continuing to check it. So yes there is benefit.

Comment: @Јοеу: (Sorry for rather the late response.) Yes, it would help, but the question was about the lack of unsigned doubles in C++. It wasn't about why hardware doesn't support it. Adding the concept to C++ without adding support for it in hardware would gain you nothing.

Comment: @Zammbi: As per my response to Joey, adding such a thing to C++ without the hardware following suit would gain you nothing. You wouldn't get a signalling underflow, so you would have to perform such checks in code. This would incur an unacceptable performance hit, no matter whether you or the compiler did so.

Comment: Of course there is a _reason_ for an unsigned double type - better type safety.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You could write `unsigned float x = -3;` and have the compiler complain. But if you subtract a larger number from a smaller number, most hardware won't catch the overflow any more than it does for unsigned int. So, yes, I'll concede that there might be a benefit, but it would be very marginal.