# C# unsigned decimal implementation

Tags: c#, decimal, unsigned

In C#, what is the proper way to implement an unsigned decimal - ie. a decimal that only accepts non-negative values.

Is there an implementation equivalent of `udecimal`?

Comment: please refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305947/5750016) about the same question :)